# How do I trigger a key event with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-listener, keycode, eventtrigger

I have the following input that I want to display an alert when the enter key is pressed. 
The input id changes on each page load, so I would like to use some of the other attributes, such as the name. 
I tried the following code, but it does not work.

```js
$('input[name="tmp_post_tag"]').keypress(function(event) {
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if (keycode == '13') {
    alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="cred_form_1046_1-textfield-6-1538886027" name="tmp_post_tag" value="" data-taxonomy="post_tag" class="wpt-new- 
    taxonomy-title js-wpt-new-taxonomy-title form-control wpt-form- 
    textfield form-textfield textfield" data-wpt-type="textfield" data-wpt- id="cred_form_1046_1_cred_form_1046_1-textfield-6-1538886027" data-wpt- name="tmp_post_tag" autocomplete="off" type="text">
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why have two `name` attribute? Also,you need to check in the view page to see if the `name` attribute still exits,due to your `input` might be used by some plugin

Comment: I tried it on my wordpress site, not working. I tried it on codepen, not working.

Comment: Show your full code or the test code,such as **jsfiddle**

Comment: I added the jquey library now I think it works fine.

Comment: Added the jquery library where?

Comment: In the html portion. Click on Run code snippet to see if it works or not.

Comment: I dont beleive you added the code.

Comment: @TheoE Open the browser console, can you see any errors? Is so please include them to your question.

Comment: It's because the edited code need to be approved

Answer (score 2):

Just import Jquery library into the HTML. It should work. And I paste the whole code as following. hope it will help you.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="cred_form_1046_1-textfield-6-1538886027" name="tmp_post_tag" value="" data-taxonomy="post_tag" class="wpt-new- 
    taxonomy-title js-wpt-new-taxonomy-title form-control wpt-form- 
    textfield form-textfield textfield" data-wpt-type="textfield" data-wpt- id="cred_form_1046_1_cred_form_1046_1-textfield-6-1538886027" data-wpt- name="tmp_post_tag" autocomplete="off" type="text">
  <script>
    $('input[name="tmp_post_tag"]').keypress(function(event) {
      var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
      if (keycode == '13') {
        alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox');
      }
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Also the script tag containing the Jquery, i mean your script not Jquery itself has an importance, because depending on where you put it you might need to check for document ready event.